# Ping site with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to ping a few sites using `javascript`, and found this pen and does what I want.

However, I don't understand when I add `goo12121212gle.com` to the list of sites as a test it comes up saying that the domain has `responded` but in the console log I see `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`??

I am new to JS but I am not sure why the below script is both saying the site is there and not at the same time? Is something missing from the script?

```
function ping(ip, callback) {

    if (!this.inUse) {
        this.status = 'unchecked';
        this.inUse = true;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.ip = ip;
        var _that = this;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.onload = function () {
            _that.inUse = false;
            _that.callback('online');

        };
        this.img.onerror = function (e) {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('offline', e);
            }

        };
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('timeout');
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
var PingModel = function (servers) {
    var self = this;
    var myServers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(servers, function (location) {
        myServers.push({
            name: location,
            status: ko.observable('unchecked')
        });
    });
    self.servers = ko.observableArray(myServers);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.servers(), function (s) {
        s.status('checking');
        new ping(s.name, function (status, e) {
            s.status(e ? "error" : status);
        });
    });
};
var komodel = new PingModel(['goo12121212gle.com','msn.com','104.46.36.174','23.97.201.12']);
ko.applyBindings(komodel);
```

https://codepen.io/lyellick0506/pen/NGJgry

Answer (score 0):

Both the onerror- and onload-callback use "responded" as the message, so there is no way to differentiate between them:

```
this.img.onerror = function (e) {
    if (_that.inUse) {
       _that.inUse = false;
       _that.callback('responded', e); // <--- change this to a different message
    }
};
```

Alternatively you could just check if the `e` parameter has been set:

```
new ping(s.name, function (status, e) {
    s.status(e ? "error" : status);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and finally had the change to try it out but still can't get it to work( I have updated my code so what you suggested but still get a responded on error

Comment: @EmmaStone that can't be. There isn't even a string "responded" in the new code. I think you forgot to update the codepen version. It should work just fine like that.